# How can we merge queries in Grafana Alerting?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I am using Grafana 9.4 for dashboarding and alerting. I would like to have an alert based on a Prometheus but **filter its results against a list of valid values from a SQL query**.

I have the equivalent in a panel in my dashboard with:

- Query A:

  - A Prometheus metric with labels like {tenant="tenant1", ...} and legend set to `{{tenant}}`. It is set with Table format and Instant type.
- Query B:

  - A SQL datasource returning a table with fields `tenant` and `is_visible`.
- Tranforms

  1. `Merge` (combines using field `tenant`)
  2. `Filter data by values` (checks for is_visible=1)
  3. `Grouping to matrix`

     - Column: tenant
     - Row: Time
     - Cell Value Value

Is this possible with alerting?

Comment: In theory: remove query B, transformation and create dashboard variable from the SQL datasource (of course with `is_visible=1` condition) and use that variable in the query A.